# Accelerate os.walk for collecting the paths of files that exist in them

Tags: python, directory-structure, os.walk

I have a directory (`data/`) that contains many sub-directories (a structure of depth 4), each of which should contain a file (e.g., an xml file named `index.xml`).

I want to create a list with all the paths where this file actually exists. The following works just fine:

```
import os

index_files = []
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk("data/"):
    file_path = os.path.join(root, "index.xml")
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        index_files.append(file_path)
```

but it can be very slow. Is there i) any alternative way of doing that (i.e., should `os.walk` be use necessarily?), and ii) any way of making this faster?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just recursively walk all the directories and record what you find in a dict by path. Then check for existence of path in the keys. This should be faster because you don't incur the cost of system call to check for existence of file.

Comment: So, you mean to avoid the existence check in the `os.walk` for loop? Didn't try that, I will, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the way you need to tackle this problem is my using the statement.

If files: # this line will check if files exist in a directory.
    If “index.xml” in files:# check if this particular file file is in the list. 
         List.append(root)# of so add the directory to the list.